# TWebBrowser - возможна ли смена движка с IE, на какой-нибудь другой?

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

Возникла мысль написать Desktop-приложения со своих всяких разных web-скриптов, аля "курс валют на рабочий стол" или "погода за окном". Но в своих web-приложениях я использовал много CSS3, который явно не поддерживается IE. (У меня установлен IE ver.8).

Так вот, хотелось бы не заставлять пользователя из-за маленькой программки с двумя циферками обновлять целый Web-браузер от корпорации Microsoft, а на стороне разработчика подменить движок в компонент TWebBrowser, чтобы он рендерил HTML, как нормальные браузеры. Т.е. чтобы ПО не зависело от IE.

Возможно ли такое?  Или же потребуется поиск и установка альтернативы для TWebBrowser?

Comment: Возможно Вам пригодится CEF - Chromium Embedded Framework. Не знаю сменяет ли он движок TWebBrowser или требуется свой компонент, но вроде как есть что-то и для delphi

Comment: TWebBrowser явно заточен под IE, причем - в режиме совместимости с какой-то древней версией. Режим совместимости можно поменять, но от IE в WB не уйти. Посему  TChromium и т.п. спасут отца русской демократии :)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже писали ранее, TWebBrowser можно запустить в режиме совместимости одной из версий IE. [Тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730.aspx%20%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%82) можно посмотреть какие ключи в реестре нужно прописать, чтобы включить соответствующий режим.

Comment: Ого, это ещё придётся и реестр юзера приложением ковырять?
Конечно реализуемо, но костыль кокой-то получается

Comment: Ну вот так у них реализован режим совместимости:) Я в итоге перешел на CEF. Там самая большая проблема была с проигрыванием flash, но и она решилась:)

Answer (score 0):

На другой движок боюсь что нет, разве что только на другую версию.
А так можно скачать дополнение библиотек с новым элементом браузера на другом движке.